# How to have both observer and on init for ember js properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, observers

New ember rules states that we need to use the below pattern

```
propObserver: Ember.observer(function () {
   //code
})
```

instead of

```
propObserver: function() {
    //code
}.observers('someProp')
```

Before updating ember we could do the below

```
propObserver: function () {
    //code
}.observes('someProp').on('init')
```

How to achieve this cascading?

Now i know we can do this separately

```
propObserver: Ember.observer('someProp', function () {
   //code
})

propObserver: Ember.on('init', function () {
       //code
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the 2.0.0 docs: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-object-initialization

```
propObserver: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('someProp', function() {
    // code
}))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I wonder how i missed it, must be a new addition there : )

Comment: I wasn't aware of that when I added my answer. I wonder if that was mentioned in Ember blog posts.